# superset 0.35.1 druid error: name 'PyDruid' is not defined

Tags: druid, apache-superset

I have installed superset 0.35.1 and pydruid module.  in python, i can load pydruid sucessfully.

```
[root@xxx superset]# python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Nov 13 2019, 15:24:35) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydruid
```

However in superset, it raised below error when connect to localhost druid.

[image: superset-load-druid-error]

Any advice?

Comment: You might be using a virtual environment for your superset and that might not have pydruid in it , depends on how you deployed the app, can you please share more details on this ?